# Stopping all async tasks in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm creating a `UIView` which runs many async tasks within a `UIViewController`. At some point I would like to be able to remove the `UIView` and stop all the tasks that are running. However, the call `removeFromSuperview()` doesn't stop the tasks. Is there a way I could do that?

**Example Code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let v = SomeView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
        self.view.addSubview(v)

        let v1 = UIButton()
        v1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        v1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        v1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeV(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(v1)
    }

    func removeV(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("V REMOVED")
        v.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

class SomeView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            var c = 0
            while true {
                print(String(c) + " DOING SOME TASK")
                c += 1
                sleep(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Logs**

```
0 DOING SOME TASK
1 DOING SOME TASK
V REMOVED
2 DOING SOME TASK
3 DOING SOME TASK
4 DOING SOME TASK
...
```

Comment: Yeh it's an example to illustrate that some task is taking place over a long period of time. When I remove the view, I would like all such tasks to stop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to cancel blocks in DispatchQueue using DispatchWorkItem. For eg.

```
//create the dispatch work item
var dwi2:DispatchWorkItem?
dwi2 = DispatchWorkItem {
    var c = 0
    while true {
        print(String(c) + " DOING SOME TASK")
        c += 1
        sleep(1)
        if (dwi2?.isCancelled)!{
            break
        }
    }
}

//submit the work item to the default global queue
DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: dwi2!)

//cancelling the task after 3 seconds
DispatchQueue.global().async{
    sleep(3)
    dwi2?.cancel()
}
```

You will have to check the isCancelled property inside your work block to stop further execution.

Please refer [this](https://medium.com/@yostane/swift-sweet-bits-the-dispatch-framework-ios-10-e34451d59a86) well written post for further details.

Answer (score 2):

In short you **can't** stop GCD task.

To add ability manage background tasks you should use `Operation` and `OperationQueue`
simple example:

```
class YourOperation: Operation {

   func execute() {
       // Execute your async task here.

       // call finish() if success finished tasks
       // call cancel() if some error
     }
}


let queue = OperationQueue()
let yourOperation = YourOperation()
queue.addOperation(yourOperation)

// to stop single operation
yourOperation.cancel()



// to stop all operations
queue.cancelAllOperations()
```

Comment: Oh I see, there's no way I could make the entire `UIView` an `Operation`?

Comment: i am not understand why you need this, you can't change UI in background thread

Comment: @VadimKozak I don't think thats what Anters is saying in his comment. I believe he meant that if he could subclass UIView with Operation Class and  call the default cancelAllOperations for his view, the answer to which would be no.

Comment: This is partially correct. You can cancel GCD operations. Please see my answer above.

Comment: @NSNoob - thats why i not understand a question, yes you can't subclass from Operations, but you can make a protocol and manage UIViews operations via protocol

Answer (score 0):

You can store a queue with tasks within your SomeView instance. Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue) for more info.

HINT: You can add as many operations, as you need and then call `-cancelAllOperations` on removal

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to complicate your life with NSOperations as others mentioned. You have the possibility to hold a flag (instead of `while true` -> `while flag`) and set it to false when you want the task to exit. This way you can also exit at any moment you want and perfectly control your flow and possible errors.

Also, to make things more robust, you could use a lockless memory barrier before that flag reads (since you'll be reading/writing it from different threads). This way you will avoid cpu caching and memory w/r order optimisation issues.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input. I'm not actually running a while true loop, it's just an illustration for the structure. I have many tasks happening over a long period of time and they are actually dynamically generated so I'm not tracking all the conditions for each one etc... I basically need to kill the entire view when the user exits the view controller